# desencriptar PASSWORD_BCRYPT me falla y no entiendo por qué

Tags: php

muy buenas,

Tengo dos formularios simples. Uno para registrarse y otro para conectarse. Al registrar lo hasheo con PASSWORD_BCRYPT y se almacena perfectamente. Luego, al pasar por el otro formulario, el de conexión, me falla con la contraseña correcta. No entiendo dónde puede estar el error y ya le he dado muchas vueltas. A ver si vuestro ojo clínico me saca del aprieto

¿Qué hago mal?

```
    <?php
function conexion(){
    try{
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mauricio','root', '');
        return $conexion;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        return false;
    }
}

$conexion = conexion();
if(!$conexion){
    echo 'error';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
        <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="submit" name="boton" value="registrar">
    </form>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
        <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="submit" name="boton" value="enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if($_POST['boton'] == 'registrar'){
            $user = $_POST['usuario'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            $pass_hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO login(id, usuario, pass) VALUE(NULL, :usuario, :pass)");
            $sentencia->execute(array('usuario' => $user, 'pass' => $pass_hash));
        }elseif($_POST['boton'] == 'enviar'){
            $user = $_POST['usuario'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];

            $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = :usuario");
            $sentencia->execute(array(':usuario' => $user));
            $passw = $sentencia->fetch();
            $passw = $passw[2];

            if(password_verify($pass, $passw)){
                echo 'muy bien!';
            }else{
                echo 'noooooo';
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: `$passw = $passw[2];` que contiene? quizas no te esta trayendo el usuario que esperas o no estas recuperando las columnas en el orden indicado  o no existe el usuario directamente, cada vez que crees un hash te va a dar un valor diferente eso es normal. A parte de lo indicado no veo nada fuera de lo normal.

Comment: Al hacer un echo de passw me trae bien la contraseña               
La base de datos contiene un id, un usuario y un pass. Como ejemplo he pasado pass hola como pass y me trae esto:
$2y$10$T0HAtm2yOBfWc

Comment: Quieres decir que se haya duplicado la contraseña? En mysql solo tengo un row

:)

Comment: Aaah, quieres decir duplicado a la pregunta. No, no. Para nada es lo mismo

Gracias de todos modos

:D

Comment: Hola Marcos,

Muchas gracias pero password_verify es lo que estoy usando desde el principio. De hecho, creo saber cómo se hace. Pero lo que no sé es ¿por qué no puedo aquí?
:D

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la estructura de la tabla `login`? Puede que la columna `pass` no sea lo suficientemente larga como para guardar la cadena que devuelve `password_hash` (_`PASSWORD_BCRYPT` El resultado siempre será un string de 60 caracteres, o FALSE en caso de error._)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Como vien te comenta Marcos si solo te esta devolviendo `$2y$10$T0HAtm2yOBfWc` parece que el hash esta truncado, por lo que el tamaño de la columna en la base de datos es insuficiente, la columna para el hash se recomienda que sea VARCHAR 255.

Comment: Mil gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda!!!! Sí que era eso...    Ya nno creo que se me olvide para la próxima :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias probar que cuando realizas el registro dejarlo asi:

```
$pass_hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

en `'PASSWORD_DEFAULT'` porque utilizas `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` cuando vas a definirle un `SALT` de lo contrario deberias usar solamente `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`, porque luego de eso no tiene ningun otro error a menos que como ya te dijeron ver si en tu base de datos tu campo es lo suficientemente grande para almacenar correctamente el `hash`.

Comment: muchas gracias por la información Fernando!

:D